# Cannot set Headers because interceptor intercept request before storing the token in local storage Angular 8 TypeScript

Tags: angular, typescript, jwt

when i try to login the interceptors doesn't set the header of the request beacause it executes before the .pipe() block of service thus currentUser in interceptors get always null
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

http-interceptor.service.ts

```
intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {


    let currentUser = this.logInService.currentUserVal;
    if (currentUser) {
      req = this.addToken(req, currentUser);
    }
    return next.handle(req).pipe(catchError(this.handleError));
  }
```

login.service.ts

```
  public _currentUserSubject: BehaviorSubject<AuthRequest>;
  public currentUser: Observable<AuthRequest>;

  public get currentUserVal(): AuthRequest {
    return this._currentUserSubject.value;
  }

  get currentUserToken() {
    return this.currentUserVal;
  }

  constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient) {

    this._currentUserSubject = new BehaviorSubject<AuthRequest>(this.getUserFromLocalStorage());
    this.currentUser = this._currentUserSubject.asObservable();

  }

  generateToken(authRequest: AuthRequest) {
    return this.httpClient.post<any>(`${this.glolabUrl}${this.authetnticationUrl}`, authRequest, { responseType: 'text' as 'json' })
      .pipe( map(user => {
          localStorage.setItem(this.JWT_TOKEN, JSON.stringify(user));
          this._currentUserSubject.next(user);
          return user;
        })
      );
  }
```

login.component.ts

```
    toAuthenticate() {
    this.submitted = true;
    if (this.loginForm.invalid) {
      return;
    }
    this.spinner.show();
    this.authSubscription = this.logInService.generateToken(this.authRequest)
    // .pipe(first())
    .subscribe(
      data => {
        this.logInService.autoritySubject.next(true);
        this.router.navigate(['home']);
        setTimeout(() => {
          this.spinner.hide();
        }, 500);
      },

      err => {
        console.log(err);
        this.spinner.show();
        this.failedMessage = err;
        this.failed = true;
        this.onReset();
        setTimeout(() => {
          this.spinner.hide();
        }, 500);
      }
    );
  }
```

Comment: First you can use `tap` instead of `map` and don't return a user. Second try `console.log` from within `map` or `tap`

Comment: Many thanks Amro, Unfortunatly It stil doesn't work :(

Answer (score 0):

you need to clone your request in HttpInterceptor, somthing like :

```
  let currentUser = this.logInService.currentUserVal;
    if (currentUser) {
       req = req.clone({
        headers: request.headers.set('Authorization', `Bearer ${currentUser.token}`)

        //req = this.addToken(req, currentUser);
    }
    //return next.handle(req).pipe(catchError(this.handleError));
    return next.handle(req).pipe(
         retry(1),
         catchError((error: HttpErrorResponse) => {
         if (error.status === 401) {
            // refresh token
         } else {
            return throwError(error);
         }
      })
   );
```

Comment: Thanks Naji but this.addToken(req, currentUser) fonction do the same things. The essentialy problem is that interceptor executes before pipe(map(...)) block of service so this._currentUserSubject.next(user) is always null and it never could read his value in interceptor

Comment: @HoudhaifaHamza i updated my answer, let me know if it fix your problem...

Comment: I try it but the same things :( the interceptor is always executes before the pipe() block of the service even if i put retry(2)  but still it doesn't work. Many thanks for you :)